# email command not working in UNIX Linux

Tags: bash, shell, redhat-enterprise-linux

I tried with 2 email UNIX commands mail and mutt from my Red Hat Linux box. It's not sending any mails to the email id I specified.

```
echo "My message" | mail -s subject "test email" <my valid emailid>

echo "My message" | mutt -s subject "test email" <my valid emailid>
```

**Outputs**: Nothing, it just shows a new shell prompt.

Could anyone please let me know what could be the problem ?

**Linux Version:**

> Linux version 2.6.18-348.4.1.el5
>   (mockbuild@x86-007.build.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704
>   (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Fri Mar 22 05:41:51 EDT 2013

Comment: Have a look at the log filess for whatever mail transfer daemon that you have installed and copy back here the relevant lines.  (I don't know where they are on redhat.  On debian, they would be in the directory `/var/log/exim4/`.)

Comment: what does the output of command `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` say ? In the newest Linux distributions, sendmail got replaced by other mail transfer agents (MTA), such as postfix. Depending your what your organization's preference is, sendmail may not be installed and will never be installed in some cases, in favor of other MTA's. You need to talk to your sysadmin, who holds the keys to the kingdom, i.e., the root password.

Answer (score 2):

If you use default mail system in `Redhat`, then you likely use `Sendmail`. When you got nothing after the command, this is expected behavior. The error doesn't directly spit out after the command. Instead take look on `/var/log/maillog`. Maybe you get a clue in there.

Comment: it says `-bash: sendmail: command not found` and i dont have permission to `/var/log/maillog` ; it says permission denied

Comment: Do you have root/sudo privilege in that box?

Comment: I am not having access

Comment: Then you may ask your administrator (person who has root access) to inspect the maillog and find out why mail doesn't sent.